# How prevent h2 content from breaking in :before content?

Tags: css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJv1F.png

Yeah i have a little problem with my :before icon.

What i want is that the h2 content is on a horizontal line and not after a line break under the :before content.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you send current code? You have probably set display of :before to block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position:absolute;left:0;` for the icon and add a `padding-left` the size of the icon to h2. Note: don't forget to set the position of h2 to relative.

**Example:**

```
h2{
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 60px; /* the size of your icon plus a spacer */
}
h2:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    height: 50px;   /* height of your icon */
    width:50px;     /* width of your icon */
    background-image:url(img/icon.png); /* your icon */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try taking your icon out of the flow completely. You need to adjust the `top` and `left` values.

```
h2 {
  position: relative
}
h2:before {
  position: absolute,
  top: 0;
  left: -20px;
}
```